# opening multiple text file in VBA as array

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using the code in this post to import several txt file. i want to put each value or string in one cell as array.but all of them put in one row so i have one column and several row.

the code is:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("G:\test")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, " ", 1)

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Plz  help me.. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you are splitting the line and putting each token in different columns. If you don't want to split them, then remove these lines.

```
' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
Items = Split(TextLine, " ", 1)

' Put data on one row in active sheet
For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
        cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
Next
```

And then just add back `cl.Value = TextLine`